# Propel: mysql extension not loaded

Tags: php, apache2, symfony1, propel

I'm having trouble with running symfony 1.4 application, propel says that mysql extension is not loaded. I wanted to uncomment line in php.ini to enable that extension but i couldn't find one, then i realized that I'm using PHP 7.0 so I downgraded to 5.6 found this line in php.ini and uncommented it, but unfortunately it didn't work. Can you give me a hint what might be wrong ?

My config:
ElementaryOS 0.4 (Loki)
Apache 2.4.18

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 1.4 won't work properly on PHP 5.6 without significant modifications to the framework.

This is not a trivial amount of work.  Take a look at https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1 which is a fork of Symfony 1.4.  It has fixed the issues so it works with PHP 7.0